# Chrome Inspect Views Needs To Be Open For Extension To Function

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, console

I've been developing a Chrome Extension, but I'm relatively new to extension development. So I apologize for my newb-ness. I've been running into a weird bug, though, and I'd appreciate any input that could point me in the right direction.

I've developed an extension that grabs content from the active tab and saves it to a database via some custom API calls. All of this happens after doing an OAuth handshake with Github. What's weird, though, is that unless the Inspect Views Background Page is open, then it neither grabs content from the active nor does it make any API calls. However, as soon as I re-open the Inspect Views console, everything works perfectly.

Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just received help from an outside source who mentioned a manifest change was necessary.

**Old Code:**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "example.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
},
```

**Correct Code:**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "example.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
},
```

This goes against the recommendation in the documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). However, it seems to be the only way to get this working.

Comment: It means your code makes wrong assumptions. The non-persistent event pages are stopped on inactivity, restarted on activity, which means the [global] variables don't keep their values.

Comment: If I change persistent back to false, do I have to list every one of the scripts javascript files in the scripts arrays?

Comment: I don't know what your code does and thus I can't answer. Try researching yourself and ask a new question if necessary.